# Axis Labeling outside Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) tutorial to build a stacked bar graph.
The y-axis label ("Population") falls within the graph and the x-axis label gets hidden by the bars. Is it possible to shift the labeling to outside the graph i.e, he y-axis labeling to the left side of the line and the x-axis labeling to below the starting of the graph ?
I've tried various text-anchor and alignment-baseline values and they never seem to work.
I'm new to d3.js so, please bear with me.
This is the code segment that adds the y-axis label:

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the axis titles as shown below.

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .append("text")
  .text("State")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + this.parentNode.getBBox().width / 2 + "," + 50 + ")";
  });


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .text("Population")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + -50 + "," + this.parentNode.getBBox().height / 2 + ") rotate(-90)";
  });
```

Note: I have placed the axis titles at the middle of axis. Adjust the transform attribute values for any positional changes. Hope this helps.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 90
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "State": "AL",
  "Under 5 Years": 310504,
  "5 to 13 Years": 552339,
  "14 to 17 Years": 259034,
  "18 to 24 Years": 450818,
  "25 to 44 Years": 1231572,
  "45 to 64 Years": 1215966,
  "65 Years and Over": 641667
}, {
  "State": "AK",
  "Under 5 Years": 52083,
  "5 to 13 Years": 85640,
  "14 to 17 Years": 42153,
  "18 to 24 Years": 74257,
  "25 to 44 Years": 198724,
  "45 to 64 Years": 183159,
  "65 Years and Over": 50277
}, {
  "State": "AZ",
  "Under 5 Years": 515910,
  "5 to 13 Years": 828669,
  "14 to 17 Years": 362642,
  "18 to 24 Years": 601943,
  "25 to 44 Years": 1804762,
  "45 to 64 Years": 1523681,
  "65 Years and Over": 862573
}, {
  "State": "AR",
  "Under 5 Years": 202070,
  "5 to 13 Years": 343207,
  "14 to 17 Years": 157204,
  "18 to 24 Years": 264160,
  "25 to 44 Years": 754420,
  "45 to 64 Years": 727124,
  "65 Years and Over": 407205
}, {
  "State": "CA",
  "Under 5 Years": 2704659,
  "5 to 13 Years": 4499890,
  "14 to 17 Years": 2159981,
  "18 to 24 Years": 3853788,
  "25 to 44 Years": 10604510,
  "45 to 64 Years": 8819342,
  "65 Years and Over": 4114496
}, {
  "State": "CO",
  "Under 5 Years": 358280,
  "5 to 13 Years": 587154,
  "14 to 17 Years": 261701,
  "18 to 24 Years": 466194,
  "25 to 44 Years": 1464939,
  "45 to 64 Years": 1290094,
  "65 Years and Over": 511094
}, {
  "State": "CT",
  "Under 5 Years": 211637,
  "5 to 13 Years": 403658,
  "14 to 17 Years": 196918,
  "18 to 24 Years": 325110,
  "25 to 44 Years": 916955,
  "45 to 64 Years": 968967,
  "65 Years and Over": 478007
}, {
  "State": "DE",
  "Under 5 Years": 59319,
  "5 to 13 Years": 99496,
  "14 to 17 Years": 47414,
  "18 to 24 Years": 84464,
  "25 to 44 Years": 230183,
  "45 to 64 Years": 230528,
  "65 Years and Over": 121688
}, {
  "State": "DC",
  "Under 5 Years": 36352,
  "5 to 13 Years": 50439,
  "14 to 17 Years": 25225,
  "18 to 24 Years": 75569,
  "25 to 44 Years": 193557,
  "45 to 64 Years": 140043,
  "65 Years and Over": 70648
}];

color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "State";
}));

data.forEach(function(d) {
  var y0 = 0;
  d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      y0: y0,
      y1: y0 += +d[name]
    };
  });
  d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
});

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.total - a.total;
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.State;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.total;
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .append("text")
  .text("State")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + this.parentNode.getBBox().width / 2 + "," + 50 + ")";
  });


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .text("Population")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + -50 + "," + this.parentNode.getBBox().height / 2 + ") rotate(-90)";
  });

var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",0)";
  });

state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ages;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y1);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```